# Counts which string appears the most

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table for example:

```
Names  Details
--------------
wilson admin
david  member
wilson admin
wilson admin
sam    member
david  member
```

Now what i want to achieve is show a table like this

```
Names  Details count
--------------------
wilson admin   3
david  member  2    
sam    member  1
```

I want to show the names according to how many times they appear

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name, Detail, COUNT(*) as Count
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Name, Detail
ORDER BY Count DESC;
```

Since you have more than one column in your output table `SELECT`, you should group by both columns.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer already

```
  SELECT names, COUNT(names) AS count
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY names ORDER BY count DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use the GROUP BY and COUNT

```
SELECT Names, Details, COUNT(NAMES) as `count` FROM `table` GROUP BY `Names`
```